# Shift tuple type by new one

Tags: arrays, typescript, arguments, tuples

I can write following code and [it works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=3&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAhgZwKZoDwGlEYAeUGYAJmomlAE4xgDmANIgGosCqLAKgHwAUAWxQAHAFyIA3ogDaAawwBPRPUS4AuhJntEXRN3WIAvgEotuFjr0GZ6gNwAoUJFgJk6LHgLFSFKrXpmNk4BYXEpWQVlVQ0tK0NTc0tOdVtHZ2h4JFRMHHwiEnJKajpGS1DRCWl5JRUkWLZjM1kLNlT7J3BMtxzPfJ8i-1Kg1grw6qi6tU1G0ykHREQaDCgQGiQAeQAjACsMaAA6KLQhURMDsP5JgF5eRH4axUN0RBQwRVtziARUKFORR6vSgaExA17vEyOIwOJxwGj3b5gaiRJQsFA0GgsZZoQxwYDuXL8SQLRaIABEKC2EDJWhkAEYWAAmFhkgCO7LJ6hYAHJWQB3DDcrkkxZksgYYA02QyAAsLAArCz0GROTy+eqhUwHKZQcTSYgAPQG5AIZFRCQUqlkxAAH3J4slIsNxsRyPRNAk-BKgVtiDAIEEWwwNBMtidRpNSKgSywEm9jG1QA):

```
function cases<K extends string, V, U, T>(map: { [key in K]: [V, U, T] }): [K, V, U, T][];
function cases<K extends string, V, U>(map: { [key in K]: [V, U] }): [K, V, U][];
function cases<K extends string, V>(map: { [key in K]: V }): [K, V][];
function cases<K extends string, V>(map: { [key in K]: V }) {
  return Object.keys(map).map(key => ([key] as any[]).concat(map[key as K]) as any);
}

for (const [key, arr, res] of cases({
    "abc": [[1, 2, "qqq"], 'qwe'],
    "def": [[4, 5, "asd"], 'www'],
})) {
    // const key: "abc" | "def"
    // const arr: (string | number)[]
    // const res: string
}
```

But I don't want to write this bunch of overloads:

```
function cases<K extends string, V, U, T>(map: { [key in K]: [V, U, T] }): [K, V, U, T][];
function cases<K extends string, V, U>(map: { [key in K]: [V, U] }): [K, V, U][];
function cases<K extends string, V>(map: { [key in K]: V }): [K, V][];
```

and want to specify some tuple type:

```
function cases<K extends string, V extends any[]>(map: { [key in K]: V }): [K, ...V] {
```

but it [doesn't compile](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAhgZwKZoDwGlEYAeUGYAJmomlAE4xgDmANIgGoHGkWIpgCeAbQC6APgAUAWxQAHAFyIA3ogEBrDH0T1EuIfPYBfAJTyBuFgDpLrIYoBQiRDQxQQNJAHkARgCsM0c2p8aJIyhuZS0mKBiAC8Iohiquo26Dz8wmEQCKhQIdJJGqk6hjyUvHwlqeUA3Lb6trbAcDQJWWDUyoEsKDQ0LE5oNnDAyOhYYgr2DogARCieEDMmAgCMLABMLDMAjrszQiwA5NsA7hiHB1MOM2QYwEvKAgAsLACsW+hk+0cnvxdMdUMJUm00QAHowcgEB1AvI5gsZogAD6zW73K7gyFtDo9GjyMTUOiMZGIMAgCSeDA0QzCDEQqHtKCOLDyQn0Bh1IA) with error

> A rest element type must be an array type.

How can I fix that?

Comment: your singleton case doesn't really match the pattern.. it should be `{[key in K]: [V]}` to match.  If that works you can use a type like `type Cons<H, T extends readonly any[]> = ((h: H, ...t: T) => void) extends ((...r: infer R) => void) ? R : never;` to prepend a type `H` to a tuple `T` instead of the unsupported `[H, ...T]` syntax.

Comment: @jcalz, can't make it working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `[H, ...T]` was [proposed](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453) but is not supported.  The support for [tuples in rest/spread positions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) allows us to represent the same concept like this instead:

```
type Cons<H, T extends readonly any[]> =
  ((h: H, ...t: T) => void) extends ((...r: infer R) => void) ? R : never;
```

Observe:

```
type ConsTest = Cons<1, [2, 3, 4]> // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So your `cases()` function could be typed like this:

```
function cases<K extends string, T extends any[]>(
  map: { [key in K]: T | [] }
): Array<Cons<K, T>> {
  return Object.keys(map).map(
    key => ([key] as any[]).concat(map[key as K]) as any
  );
}
```

Here we are returning `Array<Cons<K, T>>` where `T` is the array type in the properties of the `map` argument.  Also note that in `map` I made the property type `T | []` instead of just `T`.  This is a [trick](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27179#issuecomment-422606990) which hints to the compiler that you'd like the type of `map` to be [inferred as a tuple if possible](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27179).  Otherwise, when you use an array literal like `["a", 1]`, this will tend to be inferred as `Array<string | number>` and not `[string, number]`.  Since your `cases()` function depends fairly heavily on prepending to a tuple, it's helpful if the compiler infers tuples for you.  This might be the reason why you were having trouble making this work?  Even without this, though, you could use [`const` assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) or other annotations to get your `map` properties to be tuples.

Okay, let's make sure this works as you intend:

```
for (const [key, arr, res] of cases({
  "abc": [[1, 2, "qqq"], 'qwe'],
  "def": [[4, 5, "asd"], 'www'],
})) {
  key; // "abc" | "def"
  arr; // (string | number) []
  res; // string
}
```

Yep, looks good.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=21&ssc=2&pln=14&pc=1#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-AuylUMqgMP8+UK8sVspOUEt1tlCwFFFDBREQ1G0YQNUWIJsqk4PyiycKaYQIz9QA)

```
for (const [key, arr, res] of cases({
  "abc": [[1, 2, "qqq"], 'qwe'],
  "def": [[4, 5, "asd"], 'www'],
})) {
  key; // "abc" | "def"
  arr; // (string | number) []
  res; // string
}
```

Comment: _"This might be the reason why you were having trouble making this work?"_ - yep, exactly)